# Copying object from one Realm to another fails on primary key conflict

Tags: swift, realm

I'd like to copy an object from one realm to another, but it's complaining that there is already an object with that primary key.

### Details:

There are two different Realms in my app. One is stored in the Caches folder and the other is the default in the Documents folder. They have the same schema. I would like to copy an object from one Realm to the other. Following the guidelines in the docs, I'm using `Realm().create(_:value:update:)` to make the copy. When I pass in the story from the ContentRealm to be created in the UserRealm, I get an exception stating that an object with the primary key already exists. However, no instances of type `Story` exist yet in the UserRealm, so there should not be a primary key conflict. `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to create an object of type 'Story' with an existing primary key value '4'.'`

Am I doing this wrong?

```
    // Copy the Story to the user database
    var userStory: Story?
    do {
        try userRealm.write {
            userStory = userRealm.create(Story.self, value:storyObjectFromContentRealm)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Could not copy story: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: maybe, userRealm is same realm file you are trying to copy from. Have you verified that the configuration url for userRealm is different from other realm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a cyclical relationship buried in my object graph. Realm's documentation warned me about this, and I thought I was okay, but turns out I was not. After modifying the relationships, I am able to successfully make a copy of an object from one realm to another.

If you're running into this issue, check your relationships.